# Configuring akka dispatcher for large amount of concurrent graphs

Tags: java, akka, akka-stream, java.util.concurrent

My current system has around 100 thousand running graphs, Each is built like that:

Amqp Source ~> Processing Stage ~> Sink

Each amqp source receives messages at a rate of 1 per second. Only around 10 thousand graphs receive messages at once, So I've figured there is no need for more than 10 thousand threads running concurrently.

These are currently the settings i'm using:

```
my-dispatcher {
  type = Dispatcher
  executor = "fork-join-executor"
  fork-join-executor {
    parallelism-min = 16
    parallelism-factor = 2.0
    parallelism-max = 32
  }
  throughput = 20
}
```

Obviously these settings are not defining enough resources for the wanted performances, So I wonder:

1. Am I correct to assume that 10 thousand threads are enough?
2. Is it possible to configure the dispatcher (by editing application.conf) for that amount of threads? How would the configuration look like? Should I pick "fork-join-executor" or "thread-pool-executor" as the executor?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Akka and Akka Streams is based on async, an actor or stream only uses a thread for a chunk of processing and then hands the thread back to the threadpool, this is nice because you can size the threadpool according the number of cores you have to actually execute the threads rather than the things you want to execute. Having many threads will have an overhead, both in scheduling/switching and in that the JVM allocates a stack of somewhere around 0.5-1Mb per thread.

So, 10 thousand actors or running streams, can still execute fine on a small thread pool. Increasing the number of threads may rather slow the processing down than make anything faster as more time is spent on switching between threads. Even the default settings may be fine and you should always benchmark when tuning to see if the changes had the effect you expected.

Generally the fork join pool gives good performance for actors and streams. The thread-pool based one is good for use cases where you cannot avoid blocking (see this section of the docs: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/dispatchers.html#blocking-needs-careful-management)

Comment: Thanks for the response! But still I can't fully understand how running 10 thousand concurrent streams on a rather small thread pool won't cause blocking between the graphs which will eventually lead to accumulation of messages on every source.